# How to add text to Clipboard in Windows Phone Runtime?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

previously in Windows Phone 8 we could use `Clipboard` to share text. It's supported in Windows 8,

```
Clipboard.SetContent(dataPackage);
```

But I see [it is not supported for Windows Phone Runtime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.applicationmodel.datatransfer.clipboard.aspx). Is it not possible anymore or there is another way to do that?

Comment: What the hell is happening in StackOverFlow? Two questions asked and both got negative vote while voters don't even read question well! **It's about Windows Phone Runtime not silverlight** @SaverioTerracciano :\

Comment: @user3646098 People usually downvote questions when a simple online search can give you an answer. For example, searching for "windows phone 8.1 winrt clipboard" gives this link as one of the first results: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn642486%28v=vs.105%29.aspx. Article on that link says that Clipboard is a "Windows Phone 8 feature for which there is no Windows Phone Store equivalent"

Comment: @igrali , Thanks. I didn't know to search about clipboard in Migrating article.. There are still less information about new version though

Comment: @igrali what people would be expecting is some workaround method to achieve the functionality on stackoverflow. a simple search actually pointed me to this question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You pretty much answered your own question. Clipboard APIs are currently available only on Windows Phone Silverlight 8.0 and 8.1, and not on Windows Phone WinRT.

More info: [Windows Phone 8.1 for Developers - Choose your Windows Phone XAML app model](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/thunbrynt/archive/2014/04/15/windows-phone-8-1-for-developers-choose-your-windows-phone-xaml-app-model.aspx)

EDIT: [Migrating your Windows Phone 8 app to a Windows Runtime XAML app](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn642486%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) states that Clipboard is a "Windows Phone 8 feature for which there is no Windows Phone Store equivalent"

Comment: So literally there isn't **any** way to put something into clipboard in Windows Phone Runtime Apps?

Answer (score 0):

there is a way to do so now using WinRT framework syntax.
Using the lib [Charming Share](https://www.nuget.org/packages/InTheHand.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer/8.2014.4.301)
Just import Clipboard class from this lib. I've tested it - works but leaves app for a while. I am presuming that this is a call to the lib written using Silverlight 8.1
Cheers!