# C# Windows Phone 8.1 Clipboard support

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, clipboard

I'm wondering if there is a copy to clipboard support in Windows Phone 8.1

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.applicationmodel.datatransfer.clipboard.aspx) it says, there is no support (no date) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.clipboard%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) it says there is (from June '14)

However if I try to compile

```
Clipboard.SetText("myClipboard Text");
```

I only get a compiling error with a `missing assembly reference` for the namespace `Clipboard`

Alternatively is there a workaround to still be able, putting text into the `Clipboard`?

Comment: The question was already answered in http://stackoverflow.com/q/24264147/438180

Comment: there is a way to do so now, check it out [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34064791/827266)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no clipboard API in Windows Runtime. You can still use it, if you build Silverlight application, but [as MSDN says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn642486%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) there's no equalient of this API for Windows Runtime apps.

Comment: Ehm, that link is for migrating Windows Phone apps to Windows Runtime, but the OP's question is about clipboard in Windows Phone 8.1 and that should be supported.

Comment: @walther assuming that OP uses Windows Runtime. Otherwise, there wouldn't be any problem.

Comment: I am not using Siverlight